# Regex for maximum 4 digit with dot, accept only number and separate with dot every thousand

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a problem to convert input in HTML to specific criteria :

- Maximum 4 digit with dot (ex : 5.100)
- Only accept number
- Separate with dot if thousand

I am able to achieve the last two with this :

`value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");`

How to add the first criteria ?

And seems like my regex is too long, a shorter one would be great.

Comment: what happens if `value` contains more than 4 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all but first four digits:

```js
const value = `123456`
console.log(
   value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^(\d{4})\d+/, '$1').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
)
```

Comment: What happens to something like `0.34`?

Comment: @Andy The question is about integers so far.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mask for the input,

```
("#id").inputmask({
                mask: "9.999", 
                placeholder: "",
                separator: "", 
               });
```

Then to check the value,

```
value.replace('.','');
```

and with a regular expression to verify that it is true that they are only digits and at most 4.

```
let regex_aux = /^\d{4}/;
 if(regex_aux.test(value)){
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: Is inputmask function Jquery ?

Comment: sorry @FadhilRadh, is a javascript library. 
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask